# How to handle HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden from PHP code

Tags: php, api, http-status-code-403

I am using the API sometimes it will return the **HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden** message. How should I handle this in code?

I want if API return **403 Forbidden** skip the below code and if its return the success continue with the below code.

Anyone can tell me how to handle the **HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden** in php code?

Return a code as below,

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

unable to check status code.

Comment: Usually there's a response-code from the API you can fetch. Check if its 200 (everything was fine) or 403 (forbidden). Which API is it?

Comment: its [geoplugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/) API

Comment: On 403 return a code like `<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>`
how should I check status in this html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of PHP's "[get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)" function I have get the status code easily and solve my problem,

```
get_headers($URL, 1); // will return all the headers sent by the server in response.
```

If it will return 200 then I will continue execute the script otherwise stop there.

When I print the response of **get_header** it will like below,

For Success(200) response as below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] => Thu, 04 May 2017 12:38:41 GMT
    [Content-Type] => text/plain; charset=utf-8
    [Content-Length] => 725
    [Connection] => close
    [Server] => Apache
    [Cache-Control] => max-age=0
    [Expires] => Thu, 04 May 2017 12:38:41 GMT
)
```

And For 403 Forbidden

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
    [Server] => geoPlugin
    [Date] => Thu, 04 May 2017 12:41:30 GMT
    [Content-Type] => text/html
    [Connection] => close
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump(http_response_code());
```

you can check the response with this and then do what you need according to the response sent